# How automate user actions in a CRM?

Tags: crm, siebel

I have a Siebel CRM, I have a set of actions that I perform daily. Is it possible to automate this? I want this is to be done from the user side. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

E.g I want the program to change the follow-up dates. So this would include changing the date and clicking done.

[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhxN0.png)

Comment: P.S - I do not want an expensive solution like selenium. Something I can build myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention which Siebel version you're running, but from IP17 onwards there's a new feature called Siebel Test Automation. Perhaps you could record a test scenario and schedule it to run in a daily basis.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/TestGuide/TestGuide_AutoFuncTest6.html

Another option would be to have a python script to instantiate a browser session and redo your required steps, try to google about python and selenium library (it's free).